# Perl regular expression help (parse out column)

Tags: regex, perl

Im stuck here. Not sure why my reg ex won't work. I have a pipe delimited text file with a series of columns. I need to extract the 3rd column.

### File:

```
A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I
2011-03-03 00:00:00.0|1|60510271|254735|27751|BBB|1|-0.1619023623|-0.009865904
2011-03-03 00:00:00.0|1|60510270|254735|27751|B|3|-0.0064786612|-0.0063739185
2011-03-03 00:00:00.0|1|60510269|254735|27751|B|3|-0.0084998226|-0.009244384
```

### Regular expression:

```
$> head foo | perl -pi -e 's/^(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)$/$3/g'
```

### Output

```
-0.1619023623
-0.0064786612
-0.0084998226
```

Clearly not the correct column being outputted.

Thoughts ?

Comment: See Bllly and Gareth for why your regex failed. In addition, you do not need the parentheses except for the one you like to pick out (the third one), and then you will replace with `$1` insread of `$3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your pattern greedy - so:

`'s/^(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*)$/$3/g'`

Comment: or match not pipes like this `s/[^\|]+\|[^\|]+\|([^\|]+)\|/$1/g`

Comment: Thanks very much. Thats works. Im using this in a perl script to parse 500,000 records. It wasnt working so I was using perl from the cmd line to test te expression which is what I pated.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, its easier/simpler(KISS) NOT to use regex for file format that have structured delimiters. Just split the string on "|" delimiter and get the 3rd field.

```
awk -F"|" '{print $3}' file
```

With Ruby(1.9+)

```
ruby -F"\|" -ane 'puts $F[2]' file
```

With Perl, its similar to the above Ruby one-liner.

```
perl -F"\|" -ane 'print $F[2]."\n"' file
```

Comment: @Zaid, yes, i always forget the `-l` switch

Answer (score 1):

`.*` will by default match as much as it can, so your RE is picking out the *last* three columns (and everything before) rather than the *first* three (and everything after). You can avoid this in (at least) two ways: (1) instead of `.*`, look for `[^|]*`, or (2) make your repetition operators non-greedy: `.*?` instead of `.*`.

(Or you could explicitly split the string instead of matching the whole thing with a single RE. You might want to try both approaches and see which performs better, if it matters. Splitting is likely to give longer but clearer code.)

Answer (score 1):

How about using a real parser instead of hacking together a regex? [`Text::CSV`](http://perlmeme.org/tutorials/parsing_csv.html) should do the job.

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({sep_char => "|"});
```

Answer (score 1):

First thought was Text::CSV (mentioned by Matt B), but if the data looks like the example I'd say [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/search.html?q=split) is the right choise.

Untested:

```
$> head foo | perl -le 'while (<>) { print (split m{|})[2]; }'
```

If you really want a regex I would use something like this:

```
s{^ [^\|]* \| [^\|]* \| ([^\|]*) \| .*$}{$1}gx;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\|)\d{8}
```

Maybe this would work `(?<=\|)`   positive look behind for a `|` character followed by 8 digits